# Lenovo Ultrabook touchpad not workinng

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ultrabook

I've just installed Ubuntu LTS 20.04.3 on a Lenovo Ultrabook.
All went fine except the touchpad.

Sorry I am confused with many posts about touchpad and I apologize if the problem is already discussed in other threads. But any help is appreciated.

Lenovo support told me to press F6. Nothing happens.

Here what I see from the shell:

```
enrico@enrico-Lenovo-V15-IIL:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
enrico@enrico-Lenovo-V15-IIL:~$
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: "Lenovo support told me to press F6. Nothing happens." are you sure it was not Fn+F6? (because it is one the function from Fn).

Comment: Quick simple thing to check - if you have a mouse, use that to open settings at the top right, then select ‘mouse and touchpad’ and check that the touchpad is enabled. On my Asus laptop, it’s fn-f9 to enable / disable the touchpad (there’s a crossed out touchpad logo on the key) and when I do that it toggles the slider switch that you can see in the settings menu.

Comment: also fn+F6 does not work. If I open the settings I only see the mouse. The touchpad is not diplayed. In other therad there are some tricks to enable it but I think noone has tried with an Ultrabook.

Comment: I saw the keyborf Function keys are not working as expected, they perform other functions in comparisono to what is written on the keybord...